# How to determine SurveyMonkey Date format?

Tags: surveymonkey

The SurveyMonkey API page has no details on how a respondent's `datetime` `date_only` answer is formatted.  But experimentally I found that it has always been in US format (`mm/dd/yyyy`, e.g. `09/24/2014`).  That is, until today, when I got several survey answers like this:

```
"respondent_id": "redacted",
"questions": [
    {
        "answers": [
            {
                "text": "25/09/2014",
                "row": "7583496481"
            }
        ],
        "question_id": "redacted"
    },
...
```

My date parsing failed because `25` is not a valid month.  This seems to be a  `dd/mm/yyyy` format.  However there are mixed formats for the same `question_id`.

Does anyone have an idea about how to predict the format of date answers?

The survey's `language_id` is `1`.

The type info for the question is:

```
"type": {
    "subtype": "date_only",
    "name": "",
    "family": "datetime"
}
```

Comment: Would be much faster if you gave some curl example with your API token redacted, then someone who has a token can quickly copy paste to play around, or even use the API console.

Comment: I suspect this is specific to the locale of the respondent.  You may want to contact api-support@surveymonkey.com about this, sounds like a bug to me that it's not consistent.

Comment: @jonnybazookatone I can't give out the ID of the survey with the bad date formatting.  This doesn't happen normally - I have imported lots of surveys with dates with no issue with the exact same API commands.

Comment: @MilesCederman-Haysom Thanks, I have emailed API support and will update here if it turns out to be a bug or otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format in which dates are collected is controlled by the design of the survey in SurveyMonkey. If the format has changed, the survey design has probably also changed.

Comment: Thanks Tony. Do you know which API call allows me to determine the date format portion of the survey design? My app deals with hundreds of SurveyMonkey users, and I need to determine this programmatically.

Comment: That's a really great question that's never come up before, Yoshi. get_survey_details offers no information about the date format for a specific question. I've requested an improvement to fix that.

Comment: Thanks again for following up Tony.  In the meanwhile it sounds like the best solution would be for me to separately ask the user for their design-time date format.  And in the case where there are mixed date formats in the same survey, might have to use heuristics or just throw my hands up in the air :-)